# What should I keep a close attention to when selecting a license for my project?

Tags: license-recommendation

There are plenty of open source licenses out there. What should a person especially keep in mind while they're selecting a license for their project?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-recommendations.html and http://choosealicense.com/

Comment: This question is too broad, maybe if you are having issues to choose, edit the question to get more useful answers. My answer right now, would be 'It depends on your goals and libraries you plan to link to your project'

Comment: @Tichodroma I know about this resource, but it is mostly consisted out of recommendations for free software -compliant licenses without actually explaining why should a person use it.

Comment: @ecelis It should be more specific now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly you want to decide if you license it permissive or not. Other than that, some licenses are matured more and are tested better in courts. [Choose a license](http://choosealicense.com/) should be helpful in picking a license.

Basically it recommends MIT if you want a permissive license, Apache if you want to consider software patents and GPL if you want to keep the project open source.