# What I should consider about licenses when starting a software project?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license, dependencies, license-creation

I'm trying to come up with all the license-related considerations I should think about when starting a software project from scratch. I believe taking into account the licenses of programming languages, frameworks, libraries and packages cover almost everything. I'm focusing mainly on software but hardware, cloud, DBMs, documentation, assets, ... also play an important role.

Then I may want to license my software project under open source or free or proprietary software licenses. So knowing the licenses of the software I need to reuse is key for license-compatibility, relicensing or attribution. And surely it has an impact on my desired outcome and may put constraints on the way.

What other stuff related to software licenses would you also consider?
By the way, I've already looked at a [similar post](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-should-i-keep-a-close-attention-to-when-selecting-a-license-for-my-project) but its not addressing my question.

Comment: You need to be much clearer about **how** the linked duplicate isn't addressing your issues.